# i am getting a php syntax error after adding js code

Tags: php

i am trying to add this js code to my site but i keep getting a error

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
>   unexpected '':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>3'
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /var/www/html/Themes/default/index.template.php on line 456" while
>   reading response header from upstream, client: ip, server:
>   mysite.comt, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com"

the code i am trying to add is from blockadblock.com

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">
// Place this code snippet near the footer of your page before the close of the /body tag
// LEGAL NOTICE: The content of this website and all associated program code are protected under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. Intentionally circumventing this code may constitute a violation of the DMCA.

eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}(';q O=\'\',28=\'1V\';1R(q i=0;i<12;i++)O+=28.X(E.N(E.K()*28.G));q 2s=6,2o=2O,2m=5k,2x=2O,2k=D(t){q o=!1,i=D(){B(k.1g){k.2Q(\'2I\',e);F.2Q(\'1U\',e)}P{k.2S(\'33\',e);F.2S(\'1W\',e)}},e=D(){B(!o&&(k.1g||5p.34===\'1U\'||k.2V===\'2X\')){o=!0;i();t()}};B(k.2V===\'2X\'){t()}P B(k.1g){k.1g(\'2I\',e);F.1g(\'1U\',e)}P{k.35(\'33\',e);F.35(\'1W\',e);q n=!1;2n{n=F.5v==5w&&k.1Y}2t(a){};B(n&&n.2q){(D r(){B(o)H;2n{n.2q(\'17\')}2t(e){H 4T(r,50)};o=!0;i();t()})()}}};F[\'\'+O+\'\']=(D(){q t={t$:\'1V+/=\',4W:D(e){q r=\'\',d,n,o,c,s,l,i,a=0;e=t.e$(e);1a(a<e.G){d=e.14(a++);n=e.14(a++);o=e.14(a++);c=d>>2;s=(d&3)<<4|n>>4;l=(n&15)<<2|o>>6;i=o&63;B(2y(n)){l=i=64}P B(2y(o)){i=64};r=r+U.t$.X(c)+U.t$.X(s)+U.t$.X(l)+U.t$.X(i)};H r},11:D(e){q n=\'\',d,l,c,s,a,i,r,o=0;e=e.1A(/[^A-4Z-56-9\\+\\/\\=]/g,\'\');1a(o<e.G){s=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));a=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));i=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));r=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));d=s<<2|a>>4;l=(a&15)<<4|i>>2;c=(i&3)<<6|r;n=n+S.T(d);B(i!=64){n=n+S.T(l)};B(r!=64){n=n+S.T(c)}};n=t.n$(n);H n},e$:D(t){t=t.1A(/;/g,\';\');q n=\'\';1R(q o=0;o<t.G;o++){q e=t.14(o);B(e<1s){n+=S.T(e)}P B(e>5a&&e<6e){n+=S.T(e>>6|6k);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}P{n+=S.T(e>>12|2R);n+=S.T(e>>6&63|1s);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}};H n},n$:D(t){q o=\'\',e=0,n=6m=1u=0;1a(e<t.G){n=t.14(e);B(n<1s){o+=S.T(n);e++}P B(n>6o&&n<2R){1u=t.14(e+1);o+=S.T((n&31)<<6|1u&63);e+=2}P{1u=t.14(e+1);2B=t.14(e+2);o+=S.T((n&15)<<12|(1u&63)<<6|2B&63);e+=3}};H o}};q r=[\'6d==\',\'5W\',\'6c=\',\'5K\',\'5U\',\'5V=\',\'61=\',\'62=\',\'66\',\'3H\',\'3j=\',\'3e=\',\'5O\',\'6B\',\'4e=\',\'4d\',\'4c=\',\'4b=\',\'4a=\',\'49=\',\'48=\',\'47=\',\'46==\',\'45==\',\'44==\',\'43==\',\'42=\',\'40\',\'3M\',\'3Z\',\'3Y\',\'3X\',\'3W\',\'3V==\',\'3U=\',\'3T=\',\'3S=\',\'3R==\',\'3Q=\',\'3P\',\'3O=\',\'3N=\',\'4f==\',\'41=\',\'4g==\',\'4x==\',\'4L=\',\'4K=\',\'4J\',\'4I==\',\'4H==\',\'4G\',\'4F==\',\'4E=\'],y=E.N(E.K()*r.G),Y=t.11(r[y]),W=Y,Q=1,w=\'#4D\',a=\'#4C\',v=\'#4B\',g=\'#4A\',M=\'\',b=\'4z!\',p=\'4y 4w 4i 4v\\\'4u 3K 4t 2H 2G. 4s\\\'s 4r.  4q 4p\\\'t?\',f=\'4o 4n 4m-4l, 4k 4j\\\'t 4h 3L U 3J 38.\',s=\'I 3b, I 3g 3d 39 2H 2G.  3a 3f 3h!\',o=0,u=0,n=\'3c.3k\',l=0,Z=e()+\'.2T\';D h(t){B(t)t=t.1S(t.G-15);q o=k.2N(\'3x\');1R(q n=o.G;n--;){q e=S(o[n].1G);B(e)e=e.1S(e.G-15);B(e===t)H!0};H!1};D m(t){B(t)t=t.1S(t.G-15);q e=k.3I;x=0;1a(x<e.G){1n=e[x].1Q;B(1n)1n=1n.1S(1n.G-15);B(1n===t)H!0;x++};H!1};D e(t){q n=\'\',o=\'1V\';t=t||30;1R(q e=0;e<t;e++)n+=o.X(E.N(E.K()*o.G));H n};D i(o){q i=[\'3F\',\'3E==\',\'3D\',\'3C\',\'2U\',\'3B==\',\'3A=\',\'3z==\',\'3y=\',\'3w==\',\'3l==\',\'3v==\',\'3u\',\'3t\',\'3s\',\'2U\'],a=[\'2F=\',\'3r==\',\'3q==\',\'3p==\',\'3o=\',\'3n\',\'3m=\',\'4M=\',\'2F=\',\'4O\',\'3i==\',\'6b\',\'6a==\',\'69==\',\'68==\',\'67=\'];x=0;1P=[];1a(x<o){c=i[E.N(E.K()*i.G)];d=a[E.N(E.K()*a.G)];c=t.11(c);d=t.11(d);q r=E.N(E.K()*2)+1;B(r==1){n=\'//\'+c+\'/\'+d}P{n=\'//\'+c+\'/\'+e(E.N(E.K()*20)+4)+\'.2T\'};1P[x]=26 24();1P[x].1X=D(){q t=1;1a(t<7){t++}};1P[x].1G=n;x++}};D C(t){};H{2i:D(t,a){B(5Z k.L==\'5Y\'){H};q o=\'0.1\',a=W,e=k.1d(\'1y\');e.1k=a;e.j.1h=\'1O\';e.j.17=\'-1o\';e.j.V=\'-1o\';e.j.1t=\'2b\';e.j.13=\'5X\';q d=k.L.36,r=E.N(d.G/2);B(r>15){q n=k.1d(\'29\');n.j.1h=\'1O\';n.j.1t=\'1r\';n.j.13=\'1r\';n.j.V=\'-1o\';n.j.17=\'-1o\';k.L.5J(n,k.L.36[r]);n.1f(e);q i=k.1d(\'1y\');i.1k=\'2W\';i.j.1h=\'1O\';i.j.17=\'-1o\';i.j.V=\'-1o\';k.L.1f(i)}P{e.1k=\'2W\';k.L.1f(e)};l=5T(D(){B(e){t((e.1T==0),o);t((e.23==0),o);t((e.1K==\'2v\'),o);t((e.1N==\'2w\'),o);t((e.1J==0),o)}P{t(!0,o)}},27)},1F:D(e,c){B((e)&&(o==0)){o=1;F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z();F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F=D(){H}}P{q f=t.11(\'5S\'),u=k.5R(f);B((u)&&(o==0)){B((2o%3)==0){q l=\'5Q=\';l=t.11(l);B(h(l)){B(u.1E.1A(/\\s/g,\'\').G==0){o=1;F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()}}}};q y=!1;B(o==0){B((2m%3)==0){B(!F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2D){q d=[\'5P==\',\'4N==\',\'5N=\',\'5M=\',\'5L=\'],m=d.G,a=d[E.N(E.K()*m)],r=a;1a(a==r){r=d[E.N(E.K()*m)]};a=t.11(a);r=t.11(r);i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1);q n=26 24(),s=26 24();n.1X=D(){i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1);s.1G=r;i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1)};s.1X=D(){o=1;i(E.N(E.K()*3)+1);F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()};n.1G=a;B((2x%3)==0){n.1W=D(){B((n.13<8)&&(n.13>0)){F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()}}};i(E.N(E.K()*3)+1);F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2D=!0};F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F=D(){H}}}}},1z:D(){B(u==1){q z=2h.6x(\'2j\');B(z>0){H!0}P{2h.6w(\'2j\',(E.K()+1)*27)}};q h=\'6u==\';h=t.11(h);B(!m(h)){q c=k.1d(\'6s\');c.1Z(\'6r\',\'6q\');c.1Z(\'34\',\'1m/6f\');c.1Z(\'1Q\',h);k.2N(\'6p\')[0].1f(c)};6n(l);k.L.1E=\'\';k.L.j.16+=\'R:1r !19\';k.L.j.16+=\'1C:1r !19\';q Z=k.1Y.23||F.2Z||k.L.23,y=F.6l||k.L.1T||k.1Y.1T,r=k.1d(\'1y\'),Q=e();r.1k=Q;r.j.1h=\'2z\';r.j.17=\'0\';r.j.V=\'0\';r.j.13=Z+\'1v\';r.j.1t=y+\'1v\';r.j.2r=w;r.j.21=\'6j\';k.L.1f(r);q d=\'<a 1Q="6i://6h.6g" j="J-1e:10.5I;J-1j:1i-1l;1c:5H;">5G-5d 5c</a>\';d=d.1A(\'5b\',e());d=d.1A(\'59\',e());q i=k.1d(\'1y\');i.1E=d;i.j.1h=\'1O\';i.j.1B=\'1I\';i.j.17=\'1I\';i.j.13=\'58\';i.j.1t=\'57\';i.j.21=\'2e\';i.j.1J=\'.6\';i.j.2d=\'2p\';i.1g(\'54\',D(){n=n.53(\'\').51().4P(\'\');F.2l.1Q=\'//\'+n});k.1D(Q).1f(i);q o=k.1d(\'1y\'),C=e();o.1k=C;o.j.1h=\'2z\';o.j.V=y/7+\'1v\';o.j.4X=Z-4V+\'1v\';o.j.4U=y/3.5+\'1v\';o.j.2r=\'#4S\';o.j.21=\'2e\';o.j.16+=\'J-1j: "4R 4Q", 1w, 1x, 1i-1l !19\';o.j.16+=\'5e-1t: 52 !19\';o.j.16+=\'J-1e: 5f !19\';o.j.16+=\'1m-1p: 1q !19\';o.j.16+=\'1C: 5u !19\';o.j.1K+=\'2L\';o.j.32=\'1I\';o.j.5F=\'1I\';o.j.5D=\'2E\';k.L.1f(o);o.j.5C=\'1r 5A 5z -5y 5x(0,0,0,0.3)\';o.j.1N=\'2f\';q W=30,Y=22,x=18,M=18;B((F.2Z<37)||(5t.13<37)){o.j.2Y=\'50%\';o.j.16+=\'J-1e: 5s !19\';o.j.32=\'5r;\';i.j.2Y=\'65%\';q W=22,Y=18,x=12,M=12};o.1E=\'<2P j="1c:#5o;J-1e:\'+W+\'1L;1c:\'+a+\';J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;J-1M:5n;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;">\'+b+\'</2P><2M j="J-1e:\'+Y+\'1L;J-1M:5m;J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;1c:\'+a+\';R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;">\'+p+\'</2M><5l j=" 1K: 2L;R-V: 0.2J;R-1B: 0.2J;R-17: 2a;R-2K: 2a; 2C:5j 5i #5g; 13: 25%;1m-1p:1q;"><p j="J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;J-1M:2A;J-1e:\'+x+\'1L;1c:\'+a+\';1m-1p:1q;">\'+f+\'</p><p j="R-V:5h;"><29 5B="U.j.1J=.9;" 5E="U.j.1J=1;"  1k="\'+e()+\'" j="2d:2p;J-1e:\'+M+\'1L;J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l; J-1M:2A;2C-4Y:2E;1C:1b;55-1c:\'+v+\';1c:\'+g+\';1C-17:2b;1C-2K:2b;13:60%;R:2a;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;" 6t="F.2l.6v();">\'+s+\'</29></p>\'}}})();F.2g=D(t,e){q n=6y.6z,o=F.6A,r=n(),i,a=D(){n()-r<e?i||o(a):t()};o(a);H{3G:D(){i=1}}};q 2u;B(k.L){k.L.j.1N=\'2f\'};2k(D(){B(k.1D(\'2c\')){k.1D(\'2c\').j.1N=\'2v\';k.1D(\'2c\').j.1K=\'2w\'};2u=F.2g(D(){F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2i(F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F,F[\'\'+O+\'\'].5q)},2s*27)});',62,410,'|||||||||||||||||||style|document||||||var|||||||||||if||function|Math|window|length|return||font|random|body||floor|zMTVChhOgwis|else||margin|String|fromCharCode|this|top||charAt||||decode||width|charCodeAt||cssText|left||important|while|10px|color|createElement|size|appendChild|addEventListener|position|sans|family|id|serif|text|thisurl|5000px|align|center|0px|128|height|c2|px|Helvetica|geneva|DIV|sSAmNctVQA|replace|bottom|padding|getElementById|innerHTML|CKoAKuIfBb|src|indexOf|30px|opacity|display|pt|weight|visibility|absolute|spimg|href|for|substr|clientHeight|load|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|onload|onerror|documentElement|setAttribute||zIndex||clientWidth|Image||new|1000|qKlsYyJtcs|div|auto|60px|babasbmsgx|cursor|10000|visible|SqJMKPugqX|sessionStorage|SyyzsHQGzn|babn|FIGTjroRwP|location|xPBqEdIoZB|try|vsEffoVzul|pointer|doScroll|backgroundColor|TUTtgHwADn|catch|uqTPBsKVTQ|hidden|none|fSaDrtlhZK|isNaN|fixed|300|c3|border|ranAlready|15px|ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|blocker|ad|DOMContentLoaded|5em|right|block|h1|getElementsByTagName|70|h3|removeEventListener|224|detachEvent|jpg|cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t|readyState|banner_ad|complete|zoom|innerWidth|||marginLeft|onreadystatechange|type|attachEvent|childNodes|640|awesome|my|Let|understand|moc|disabled|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTI|me|have|in|c3F1YXJlLWFkLnBuZw|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTE|kcolbdakcolb|YWRzLnlhaG9vLmNvbQ|YWRjbGllbnQtMDAyMTQ3LWhvc3QxLWJhbm5lci1hZC5qcGc|MTM2N19hZC1jbGllbnRJRDI0NjQuanBn|c2t5c2NyYXBlci5qcGc|NzIweDkwLmpwZw|NDY4eDYwLmpwZw|YmFubmVyLmpwZw|YXMuaW5ib3guY29t|YWRzYXR0LmVzcG4uc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|YWRzYXR0LmFiY25ld3Muc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|YWRzLnp5bmdhLmNvbQ|cHJvbW90ZS5wYWlyLmNvbQ|script|Y2FzLmNsaWNrYWJpbGl0eS5jb20|YWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuYW9sLmNvbQ|YWdvZGEubmV0L2Jhbm5lcnM|YS5saXZlc3BvcnRtZWRpYS5ldQ|YWQuZm94bmV0d29ya3MuY29t|anVpY3lhZHMuY29t|YWQubWFpbC5ydQ|YWRuLmViYXkuY29t|clear|YWQtY29udGFpbmVy|styleSheets|site|using|making|RGl2QWQy|YWRiYW5uZXI|YWRCYW5uZXI|YmFubmVyX2Fk|YWRUZWFzZXI|Z2xpbmtzd3JhcHBlcg|QWRDb250YWluZXI|QWRCb3gxNjA|QWREaXY|QWRJbWFnZQ|RGl2QWRD|RGl2QWRC|RGl2QWRB|RGl2QWQz|RGl2QWQx|YmFubmVyYWQ|RGl2QWQ|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wNA|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMw|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMg|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMQ|QWRMYXllcjI|QWRMYXllcjE|QWRGcmFtZTQ|QWRGcmFtZTM|QWRGcmFtZTI|QWRGcmFtZTE|QWRBcmVh|QWQ3Mjh4OTA|YWRBZA|IGFkX2JveA|keep|like|can|we|income|advertising|without|But|doesn|Who|okay|That|an|re|you|looks|YWRfY2hhbm5lbA|It|Welcome|FFFFFF|000000|777777|EEEEEE|c3BvbnNvcmVkX2xpbms|b3V0YnJhaW4tcGFpZA|Z29vZ2xlX2Fk|YWRzZW5zZQ|cG9wdXBhZA|YWRzbG90|YmFubmVyaWQ|YWRzZXJ2ZXI|Q0ROLTMzNC0xMDktMTM3eC1hZC1iYW5uZXI|Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vYWR4L2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLmljbw|YWQtbGFyZ2UucG5n|join|Black|Arial|fff|setTimeout|minHeight|120|encode|minWidth|radius|Za||reverse|normal|split|click|background|z0|40px|160px|FILLVECTID2|127|FILLVECTID1|solutions|adblock|line|16pt|CCC|35px|solid|1px|112|hr|500|200|999|event|aVulzVuAfW|45px|18pt|screen|12px|frameElement|null|rgba|8px|24px|14px|onmouseover|boxShadow|borderRadius|onmouseout|marginRight|Anti|black|5pt|insertBefore|YWQtaGVhZGVy|Ly93d3cuZG91YmxlY2xpY2tieWdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|Ly9hZHMudHdpdHRlci5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZy55YWhvby5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|QWQzMDB4MTQ1|Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9hZHNlbnNlL3N0YXJ0L2ltYWdlcy9mYXZpY29uLmljbw|Ly9wYWdlYWQyLmdvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbS9wYWdlYWQvanMvYWRzYnlnb29nbGUuanM|querySelector|aW5zLmFkc2J5Z29vZ2xl|setInterval|YWQtaW1n|YWQtaW5uZXI|YWRCYW5uZXJXcmFw|468px|undefined|typeof||YWQtbGFiZWw|YWQtbGI||||YWQtZm9vdGVy|YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudC0zNDMyMy5qcGc|d2lkZV9za3lzY3JhcGVyLmpwZw|bGFyZ2VfYmFubmVyLmdpZg|YmFubmVyX2FkLmdpZg|ZmF2aWNvbjEuaWNv|YWQtZnJhbWU|YWQtbGVmdA|2048|css|com|blockadblock|http|9999|192|innerHeight|c1|clearInterval|191|head|stylesheet|rel|link|onclick|Ly95dWkueWFob29hcGlzLmNvbS8zLjE4LjEvYnVpbGQvY3NzcmVzZXQvY3NzcmVzZXQtbWluLmNzcw|reload|setItem|getItem|Date|now|requestAnimationFrame|QWQzMDB4MjUw'.split('|'),0,{}));
</script>
```

Comment: Show your full code. It sounds like this script tag is inside an echo with single quotes. You might want to break out of the PHP tags before you add this to the page.

Comment: i did it was not working for me Heredoc  worked for me :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are printing the code you posted in the question with PHP, try using [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax, like this:

```
$code = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">
// Place this code snippet near the footer of your page before the close of the /body tag
// LEGAL NOTICE: The content of this website and all associated program code are protected under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. Intentionally circumventing this code may constitute a violation of the DMCA.

eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}(';q O=\'\',28=\'1V\';1R(q i=0;i<12;i++)O+=28.X(E.N(E.K()*28.G));q 2s=6,2o=2O,2m=5k,2x=2O,2k=D(t){q o=!1,i=D(){B(k.1g){k.2Q(\'2I\',e);F.2Q(\'1U\',e)}P{k.2S(\'33\',e);F.2S(\'1W\',e)}},e=D(){B(!o&&(k.1g||5p.34===\'1U\'||k.2V===\'2X\')){o=!0;i();t()}};B(k.2V===\'2X\'){t()}P B(k.1g){k.1g(\'2I\',e);F.1g(\'1U\',e)}P{k.35(\'33\',e);F.35(\'1W\',e);q n=!1;2n{n=F.5v==5w&&k.1Y}2t(a){};B(n&&n.2q){(D r(){B(o)H;2n{n.2q(\'17\')}2t(e){H 4T(r,50)};o=!0;i();t()})()}}};F[\'\'+O+\'\']=(D(){q t={t$:\'1V+/=\',4W:D(e){q r=\'\',d,n,o,c,s,l,i,a=0;e=t.e$(e);1a(a<e.G){d=e.14(a++);n=e.14(a++);o=e.14(a++);c=d>>2;s=(d&3)<<4|n>>4;l=(n&15)<<2|o>>6;i=o&63;B(2y(n)){l=i=64}P B(2y(o)){i=64};r=r+U.t$.X(c)+U.t$.X(s)+U.t$.X(l)+U.t$.X(i)};H r},11:D(e){q n=\'\',d,l,c,s,a,i,r,o=0;e=e.1A(/[^A-4Z-56-9\\+\\/\\=]/g,\'\');1a(o<e.G){s=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));a=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));i=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));r=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));d=s<<2|a>>4;l=(a&15)<<4|i>>2;c=(i&3)<<6|r;n=n+S.T(d);B(i!=64){n=n+S.T(l)};B(r!=64){n=n+S.T(c)}};n=t.n$(n);H n},e$:D(t){t=t.1A(/;/g,\';\');q n=\'\';1R(q o=0;o<t.G;o++){q e=t.14(o);B(e<1s){n+=S.T(e)}P B(e>5a&&e<6e){n+=S.T(e>>6|6k);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}P{n+=S.T(e>>12|2R);n+=S.T(e>>6&63|1s);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}};H n},n$:D(t){q o=\'\',e=0,n=6m=1u=0;1a(e<t.G){n=t.14(e);B(n<1s){o+=S.T(n);e++}P B(n>6o&&n<2R){1u=t.14(e+1);o+=S.T((n&31)<<6|1u&63);e+=2}P{1u=t.14(e+1);2B=t.14(e+2);o+=S.T((n&15)<<12|(1u&63)<<6|2B&63);e+=3}};H o}};q r=[\'6d==\',\'5W\',\'6c=\',\'5K\',\'5U\',\'5V=\',\'61=\',\'62=\',\'66\',\'3H\',\'3j=\',\'3e=\',\'5O\',\'6B\',\'4e=\',\'4d\',\'4c=\',\'4b=\',\'4a=\',\'49=\',\'48=\',\'47=\',\'46==\',\'45==\',\'44==\',\'43==\',\'42=\',\'40\',\'3M\',\'3Z\',\'3Y\',\'3X\',\'3W\',\'3V==\',\'3U=\',\'3T=\',\'3S=\',\'3R==\',\'3Q=\',\'3P\',\'3O=\',\'3N=\',\'4f==\',\'41=\',\'4g==\',\'4x==\',\'4L=\',\'4K=\',\'4J\',\'4I==\',\'4H==\',\'4G\',\'4F==\',\'4E=\'],y=E.N(E.K()*r.G),Y=t.11(r[y]),W=Y,Q=1,w=\'#4D\',a=\'#4C\',v=\'#4B\',g=\'#4A\',M=\'\',b=\'4z!\',p=\'4y 4w 4i 4v\\\'4u 3K 4t 2H 2G. 4s\\\'s 4r.  4q 4p\\\'t?\',f=\'4o 4n 4m-4l, 4k 4j\\\'t 4h 3L U 3J 38.\',s=\'I 3b, I 3g 3d 39 2H 2G.  3a 3f 3h!\',o=0,u=0,n=\'3c.3k\',l=0,Z=e()+\'.2T\';D h(t){B(t)t=t.1S(t.G-15);q o=k.2N(\'3x\');1R(q n=o.G;n--;){q e=S(o[n].1G);B(e)e=e.1S(e.G-15);B(e===t)H!0};H!1};D m(t){B(t)t=t.1S(t.G-15);q e=k.3I;x=0;1a(x<e.G){1n=e[x].1Q;B(1n)1n=1n.1S(1n.G-15);B(1n===t)H!0;x++};H!1};D e(t){q n=\'\',o=\'1V\';t=t||30;1R(q e=0;e<t;e++)n+=o.X(E.N(E.K()*o.G));H n};D i(o){q i=[\'3F\',\'3E==\',\'3D\',\'3C\',\'2U\',\'3B==\',\'3A=\',\'3z==\',\'3y=\',\'3w==\',\'3l==\',\'3v==\',\'3u\',\'3t\',\'3s\',\'2U\'],a=[\'2F=\',\'3r==\',\'3q==\',\'3p==\',\'3o=\',\'3n\',\'3m=\',\'4M=\',\'2F=\',\'4O\',\'3i==\',\'6b\',\'6a==\',\'69==\',\'68==\',\'67=\'];x=0;1P=[];1a(x<o){c=i[E.N(E.K()*i.G)];d=a[E.N(E.K()*a.G)];c=t.11(c);d=t.11(d);q r=E.N(E.K()*2)+1;B(r==1){n=\'//\'+c+\'/\'+d}P{n=\'//\'+c+\'/\'+e(E.N(E.K()*20)+4)+\'.2T\'};1P[x]=26 24();1P[x].1X=D(){q t=1;1a(t<7){t++}};1P[x].1G=n;x++}};D C(t){};H{2i:D(t,a){B(5Z k.L==\'5Y\'){H};q o=\'0.1\',a=W,e=k.1d(\'1y\');e.1k=a;e.j.1h=\'1O\';e.j.17=\'-1o\';e.j.V=\'-1o\';e.j.1t=\'2b\';e.j.13=\'5X\';q d=k.L.36,r=E.N(d.G/2);B(r>15){q n=k.1d(\'29\');n.j.1h=\'1O\';n.j.1t=\'1r\';n.j.13=\'1r\';n.j.V=\'-1o\';n.j.17=\'-1o\';k.L.5J(n,k.L.36[r]);n.1f(e);q i=k.1d(\'1y\');i.1k=\'2W\';i.j.1h=\'1O\';i.j.17=\'-1o\';i.j.V=\'-1o\';k.L.1f(i)}P{e.1k=\'2W\';k.L.1f(e)};l=5T(D(){B(e){t((e.1T==0),o);t((e.23==0),o);t((e.1K==\'2v\'),o);t((e.1N==\'2w\'),o);t((e.1J==0),o)}P{t(!0,o)}},27)},1F:D(e,c){B((e)&&(o==0)){o=1;F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z();F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F=D(){H}}P{q f=t.11(\'5S\'),u=k.5R(f);B((u)&&(o==0)){B((2o%3)==0){q l=\'5Q=\';l=t.11(l);B(h(l)){B(u.1E.1A(/\\s/g,\'\').G==0){o=1;F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()}}}};q y=!1;B(o==0){B((2m%3)==0){B(!F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2D){q d=[\'5P==\',\'4N==\',\'5N=\',\'5M=\',\'5L=\'],m=d.G,a=d[E.N(E.K()*m)],r=a;1a(a==r){r=d[E.N(E.K()*m)]};a=t.11(a);r=t.11(r);i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1);q n=26 24(),s=26 24();n.1X=D(){i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1);s.1G=r;i(E.N(E.K()*2)+1)};s.1X=D(){o=1;i(E.N(E.K()*3)+1);F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()};n.1G=a;B((2x%3)==0){n.1W=D(){B((n.13<8)&&(n.13>0)){F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1z()}}};i(E.N(E.K()*3)+1);F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2D=!0};F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F=D(){H}}}}},1z:D(){B(u==1){q z=2h.6x(\'2j\');B(z>0){H!0}P{2h.6w(\'2j\',(E.K()+1)*27)}};q h=\'6u==\';h=t.11(h);B(!m(h)){q c=k.1d(\'6s\');c.1Z(\'6r\',\'6q\');c.1Z(\'34\',\'1m/6f\');c.1Z(\'1Q\',h);k.2N(\'6p\')[0].1f(c)};6n(l);k.L.1E=\'\';k.L.j.16+=\'R:1r !19\';k.L.j.16+=\'1C:1r !19\';q Z=k.1Y.23||F.2Z||k.L.23,y=F.6l||k.L.1T||k.1Y.1T,r=k.1d(\'1y\'),Q=e();r.1k=Q;r.j.1h=\'2z\';r.j.17=\'0\';r.j.V=\'0\';r.j.13=Z+\'1v\';r.j.1t=y+\'1v\';r.j.2r=w;r.j.21=\'6j\';k.L.1f(r);q d=\'<a 1Q="6i://6h.6g" j="J-1e:10.5I;J-1j:1i-1l;1c:5H;">5G-5d 5c</a>\';d=d.1A(\'5b\',e());d=d.1A(\'59\',e());q i=k.1d(\'1y\');i.1E=d;i.j.1h=\'1O\';i.j.1B=\'1I\';i.j.17=\'1I\';i.j.13=\'58\';i.j.1t=\'57\';i.j.21=\'2e\';i.j.1J=\'.6\';i.j.2d=\'2p\';i.1g(\'54\',D(){n=n.53(\'\').51().4P(\'\');F.2l.1Q=\'//\'+n});k.1D(Q).1f(i);q o=k.1d(\'1y\'),C=e();o.1k=C;o.j.1h=\'2z\';o.j.V=y/7+\'1v\';o.j.4X=Z-4V+\'1v\';o.j.4U=y/3.5+\'1v\';o.j.2r=\'#4S\';o.j.21=\'2e\';o.j.16+=\'J-1j: "4R 4Q", 1w, 1x, 1i-1l !19\';o.j.16+=\'5e-1t: 52 !19\';o.j.16+=\'J-1e: 5f !19\';o.j.16+=\'1m-1p: 1q !19\';o.j.16+=\'1C: 5u !19\';o.j.1K+=\'2L\';o.j.32=\'1I\';o.j.5F=\'1I\';o.j.5D=\'2E\';k.L.1f(o);o.j.5C=\'1r 5A 5z -5y 5x(0,0,0,0.3)\';o.j.1N=\'2f\';q W=30,Y=22,x=18,M=18;B((F.2Z<37)||(5t.13<37)){o.j.2Y=\'50%\';o.j.16+=\'J-1e: 5s !19\';o.j.32=\'5r;\';i.j.2Y=\'65%\';q W=22,Y=18,x=12,M=12};o.1E=\'<2P j="1c:#5o;J-1e:\'+W+\'1L;1c:\'+a+\';J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;J-1M:5n;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;">\'+b+\'</2P><2M j="J-1e:\'+Y+\'1L;J-1M:5m;J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;1c:\'+a+\';R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;">\'+p+\'</2M><5l j=" 1K: 2L;R-V: 0.2J;R-1B: 0.2J;R-17: 2a;R-2K: 2a; 2C:5j 5i #5g; 13: 25%;1m-1p:1q;"><p j="J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;J-1M:2A;J-1e:\'+x+\'1L;1c:\'+a+\';1m-1p:1q;">\'+f+\'</p><p j="R-V:5h;"><29 5B="U.j.1J=.9;" 5E="U.j.1J=1;"  1k="\'+e()+\'" j="2d:2p;J-1e:\'+M+\'1L;J-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l; J-1M:2A;2C-4Y:2E;1C:1b;55-1c:\'+v+\';1c:\'+g+\';1C-17:2b;1C-2K:2b;13:60%;R:2a;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;" 6t="F.2l.6v();">\'+s+\'</29></p>\'}}})();F.2g=D(t,e){q n=6y.6z,o=F.6A,r=n(),i,a=D(){n()-r<e?i||o(a):t()};o(a);H{3G:D(){i=1}}};q 2u;B(k.L){k.L.j.1N=\'2f\'};2k(D(){B(k.1D(\'2c\')){k.1D(\'2c\').j.1N=\'2v\';k.1D(\'2c\').j.1K=\'2w\'};2u=F.2g(D(){F[\'\'+O+\'\'].2i(F[\'\'+O+\'\'].1F,F[\'\'+O+\'\'].5q)},2s*27)});',62,410,'|||||||||||||||||||style|document||||||var|||||||||||if||function|Math|window|length|return||font|random|body||floor|zMTVChhOgwis|else||margin|String|fromCharCode|this|top||charAt||||decode||width|charCodeAt||cssText|left||important|while|10px|color|createElement|size|appendChild|addEventListener|position|sans|family|id|serif|text|thisurl|5000px|align|center|0px|128|height|c2|px|Helvetica|geneva|DIV|sSAmNctVQA|replace|bottom|padding|getElementById|innerHTML|CKoAKuIfBb|src|indexOf|30px|opacity|display|pt|weight|visibility|absolute|spimg|href|for|substr|clientHeight|load|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|onload|onerror|documentElement|setAttribute||zIndex||clientWidth|Image||new|1000|qKlsYyJtcs|div|auto|60px|babasbmsgx|cursor|10000|visible|SqJMKPugqX|sessionStorage|SyyzsHQGzn|babn|FIGTjroRwP|location|xPBqEdIoZB|try|vsEffoVzul|pointer|doScroll|backgroundColor|TUTtgHwADn|catch|uqTPBsKVTQ|hidden|none|fSaDrtlhZK|isNaN|fixed|300|c3|border|ranAlready|15px|ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|blocker|ad|DOMContentLoaded|5em|right|block|h1|getElementsByTagName|70|h3|removeEventListener|224|detachEvent|jpg|cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t|readyState|banner_ad|complete|zoom|innerWidth|||marginLeft|onreadystatechange|type|attachEvent|childNodes|640|awesome|my|Let|understand|moc|disabled|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTI|me|have|in|c3F1YXJlLWFkLnBuZw|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTE|kcolbdakcolb|YWRzLnlhaG9vLmNvbQ|YWRjbGllbnQtMDAyMTQ3LWhvc3QxLWJhbm5lci1hZC5qcGc|MTM2N19hZC1jbGllbnRJRDI0NjQuanBn|c2t5c2NyYXBlci5qcGc|NzIweDkwLmpwZw|NDY4eDYwLmpwZw|YmFubmVyLmpwZw|YXMuaW5ib3guY29t|YWRzYXR0LmVzcG4uc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|YWRzYXR0LmFiY25ld3Muc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|YWRzLnp5bmdhLmNvbQ|cHJvbW90ZS5wYWlyLmNvbQ|script|Y2FzLmNsaWNrYWJpbGl0eS5jb20|YWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuYW9sLmNvbQ|YWdvZGEubmV0L2Jhbm5lcnM|YS5saXZlc3BvcnRtZWRpYS5ldQ|YWQuZm94bmV0d29ya3MuY29t|anVpY3lhZHMuY29t|YWQubWFpbC5ydQ|YWRuLmViYXkuY29t|clear|YWQtY29udGFpbmVy|styleSheets|site|using|making|RGl2QWQy|YWRiYW5uZXI|YWRCYW5uZXI|YmFubmVyX2Fk|YWRUZWFzZXI|Z2xpbmtzd3JhcHBlcg|QWRDb250YWluZXI|QWRCb3gxNjA|QWREaXY|QWRJbWFnZQ|RGl2QWRD|RGl2QWRC|RGl2QWRB|RGl2QWQz|RGl2QWQx|YmFubmVyYWQ|RGl2QWQ|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wNA|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMw|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMg|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMQ|QWRMYXllcjI|QWRMYXllcjE|QWRGcmFtZTQ|QWRGcmFtZTM|QWRGcmFtZTI|QWRGcmFtZTE|QWRBcmVh|QWQ3Mjh4OTA|YWRBZA|IGFkX2JveA|keep|like|can|we|income|advertising|without|But|doesn|Who|okay|That|an|re|you|looks|YWRfY2hhbm5lbA|It|Welcome|FFFFFF|000000|777777|EEEEEE|c3BvbnNvcmVkX2xpbms|b3V0YnJhaW4tcGFpZA|Z29vZ2xlX2Fk|YWRzZW5zZQ|cG9wdXBhZA|YWRzbG90|YmFubmVyaWQ|YWRzZXJ2ZXI|Q0ROLTMzNC0xMDktMTM3eC1hZC1iYW5uZXI|Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vYWR4L2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLmljbw|YWQtbGFyZ2UucG5n|join|Black|Arial|fff|setTimeout|minHeight|120|encode|minWidth|radius|Za||reverse|normal|split|click|background|z0|40px|160px|FILLVECTID2|127|FILLVECTID1|solutions|adblock|line|16pt|CCC|35px|solid|1px|112|hr|500|200|999|event|aVulzVuAfW|45px|18pt|screen|12px|frameElement|null|rgba|8px|24px|14px|onmouseover|boxShadow|borderRadius|onmouseout|marginRight|Anti|black|5pt|insertBefore|YWQtaGVhZGVy|Ly93d3cuZG91YmxlY2xpY2tieWdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|Ly9hZHMudHdpdHRlci5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZy55YWhvby5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|QWQzMDB4MTQ1|Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9hZHNlbnNlL3N0YXJ0L2ltYWdlcy9mYXZpY29uLmljbw|Ly9wYWdlYWQyLmdvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbS9wYWdlYWQvanMvYWRzYnlnb29nbGUuanM|querySelector|aW5zLmFkc2J5Z29vZ2xl|setInterval|YWQtaW1n|YWQtaW5uZXI|YWRCYW5uZXJXcmFw|468px|undefined|typeof||YWQtbGFiZWw|YWQtbGI||||YWQtZm9vdGVy|YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudC0zNDMyMy5qcGc|d2lkZV9za3lzY3JhcGVyLmpwZw|bGFyZ2VfYmFubmVyLmdpZg|YmFubmVyX2FkLmdpZg|ZmF2aWNvbjEuaWNv|YWQtZnJhbWU|YWQtbGVmdA|2048|css|com|blockadblock|http|9999|192|innerHeight|c1|clearInterval|191|head|stylesheet|rel|link|onclick|Ly95dWkueWFob29hcGlzLmNvbS8zLjE4LjEvYnVpbGQvY3NzcmVzZXQvY3NzcmVzZXQtbWluLmNzcw|reload|setItem|getItem|Date|now|requestAnimationFrame|QWQzMDB4MjUw'.split('|'),0,{}));
</script>
EOT;
echo $code;
```